# Complex keyValue pair String to json using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

The below one is my keyvalue pair String. I've tried many ways but not able to solve it. here i can't do any split by comma or replacement with other String. the result i got from below code and libraries are:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet;
    
ResultSet rs = client.submit(queryString);
List<Result> results = rs.all().get(); 
System.out.println(results.toString());


[result{object=path[{id=User6, label=User, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=196000000000, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=379000000000, USER_NAME=BritTest1, USER_ID=AIDAS3L75VZIP4F7ROFS6, USER_ARN=arn:aws:iam::196226166352:user/BritTest1, sfid=6, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Tue Nov 24 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Tue Nov 24 05:30:00 IST 2020}, {id=Rel26, label=User to Policy, IN={id=Policy56, label=Policy}, OUT={id=User6, label=User}, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=196226000000.00, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=378564000000.00, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Wed Nov 25 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Wed Nov 25 05:30:00 IST 2020}, {id=Policy56, label=Policy, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=196226000000, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=378564000000, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Wed Oct 28 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Wed Oct 28 05:30:00 IST 2020, POLICY_NAME=BritReadS3Policy, POLICY_ID=ANPAS3L75VZIGNCUV274M, POLICY_ARN=arn:aws:iam::196226166352:policy/BritReadS3Policy, POLICY_DOCUMENT={"Statement":[{"Action":["s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus","s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock","s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration","s3:GetBucketTagging","s3:GetInventoryConfiguration","s3:GetBucketWebsite","s3:GetBucketLogging","s3:ListBucket","s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration","s3:GetBucketVersioning","s3:GetBucketAcl","s3:GetBucketNotification","s3:GetBucketPolicy","s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration","s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration","s3:GetIntelligentTieringConfiguration","s3:GetBucketRequestPayment","s3:GetBucketCORS","s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration","s3:GetMetricsConfiguration","s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls","s3:GetBucketLocation"],"Effect":"Allow","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::testbritive","Sid":"VisualEditor0"},{"Action":"s3:ListAllMyBuckets","Effect":"Allow","Resource":"*","Sid":"VisualEditor1"}],"Version":"2012-10-17"}, SF_ID=56, POLICY_TYPE=Customer-Managed}] class=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedPath}, result{object=path[{id=User6, label=User, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=196000000000, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=379000000000, USER_NAME=BritTest1, USER_ID=AIDAS3L75VZIP4F7ROFS6, USER_ARN=arn:aws:iam::196226166352:user/BritTest1, sfid=6, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Tue Nov 24 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Tue Nov 24 05:30:00 IST 2020}, {id=Rel1066, label=User to Policy, IN={id=Policy138, label=Policy}, OUT={id=User6, label=User}, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=196226000000.00, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=378564000000.00, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Wed Nov 25 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Wed Nov 25 05:30:00 IST 2020}, {id=Policy138, label=Policy, ORIGIN=AWS, ACCOUNT_ID=546836000000, TENANT_ID=sigma, ORG_ID=378564000000, STATUS=Ready, CREATED_AT=Wed Oct 28 05:30:00 IST 2020, UPDATED_AT=Wed Oct 28 05:30:00 IST 2020, POLICY_NAME=IAMUserChangePassword, POLICY_ID=NA, POLICY_ARN=arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMUserChangePassword, POLICY_DOCUMENT={"Statement":[{"Action":["iam:ChangePassword"],"Effect":"Allow","Resource":["arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"]},{"Action":["iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"],"Effect":"Allow","Resource":"*"}],"Version":"2012-10-17"}, SF_ID=138, POLICY_TYPE=AWS-Managed}] class=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedPath}]
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336250/convert-gremlin-console-output-into-json . No experience with graph dbs, just trying to help.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: normal json structured string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ObjectMapper to do this type of conversion
add these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

then try the following...

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = newObjectMapper();
try{
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapYouWantToConvert);
    System.out.println(json);
} catch(JsonProcessingException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm not having it as map. It is a ResultSet.
class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedPath cannot be cast to class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedPath and org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex are in unnamed module of loader 'app') (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result["vertex"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)

Comment: No matter its a map or resuiltset you will get json output. @Mani

Comment: I've pasted the exception please take a look thanks for your answer @MDRuhulAmin

Comment: it is working thanks

Comment: Welcome dear friend.